# Pull to refresh not disabling on particular screens (React js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

Iam trying to do is prevent the default state for forms in react app, in mobile view on default pull to refresh is there, 
   So if i accidentally do pull to refresh my page(form component) whole form value will be reset. Is there any way to prevent that component from pull to refresh, i tried with onTouchMove method and try to call event.preventDefault(), 
   but onTouchMove method is not firing, please let me know if there are some others methods to solve this issue, thanks in advance!.

`

```
class SwipeTest extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.state = {
            startX: 0,
            startY: 0,
            currentX: 0,
            currentY: 0,
            direction: 'none',
            threshold: 150,
    }
    }

    touchStart(e) {
        alert("i am in touchStart")
    }

    touchMove(e) {
                alert("i am in touchMove")
    }

    touchEnd(e) 
  {
            alert("i am in touchEnd")

   }

  render() {
    return (
        <div
          className="w-100 bg-blue db pa4"
          onTouchStart={this.touchStart.bind(this)}
          onTouchMove={this.touchMove.bind(this)}
          onTouchEnd={this.touchEnd.bind(this)}
         >
          Swipe me (up or down)
        </div>
    )
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <SwipeTest />,
    document.getElementById("main")
  );
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about your problem so I googled a solution. The one I found basically created a wrapper around your content and with a higher z index capture the pull event and prevent it to reach your browser.

```css
.body,
.wrapper {
  /* Break the flow */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;

  /* Give them all the available space */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  /* Remove the margins if any */
  margin: 0;

  /* Allow them to scroll down the document */
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.body {
  /* Sending body at the bottom of the stack */
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper {
  /* Making the wrapper stack above the body */
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Put the above styles here -->
</head>
<body class="body">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Your content goes here -->
    <div id="root" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the source of the idea: https://w3bits.com/prevent-chrome-pull-to-refresh-css/